# Behavior of ## changes inside Position function?

Tags: list-manipulation, pure-function

I don't understand the behavior of this following simple(?) example:

```
##&/@ {{0,1},{1,2}}
Position[%,{1,2}]
```

gives

```
{{2}}
```

which is what I expect.

However, if I try to combine these two commands as follows

```
Position[##,#]&/@ {{0,1},{1,2}}
```

i get

```
{{{}},{{}}}
```

Why does this happen?

It must be that when inside position ## doesn't give {{0,1},{1,2}}, but then why does it give it when I just use ## (it can't just be a missing set of brackets, since I have tried adding brackets inside the Position function, unless I did so incorrectly)

Comment: Maybe it will help you to inspect the output of `ClearAll[f];f[##,#]&/@ {{0,1},{1,2}}`. That might ring a bell. Moreover, `##` does nothing different from `#` in this case as the mapped function is supplied only with a single argument.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks, that helps. I was thinking about it as 2 different arguments, since `Map` first applies the argument `{0,1}` and then applies `{1,2}`. Any chance you can give an example of supplying 2 or more arguments with Map? I tried incorporating something like `[a,b,c,d]` like what the documentation has for SlotSequence, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: If I am honest, I did not even understand what the goal was that your tried to achieve. Maybe I can help you if you elaborate a bit more...

Comment: Now I am just curious if Map can be used with multiple arguments. Earlier i was trying to use the position of the expression in Map as an index. To elaborate, `{0,1}` has position 1 in `{{0,1},{1,2}}`. I was trying to set a variable = to the position. I can just define an index variable and use a loop or something though, and index through every iteration of the loop., so getting the code in the question to work is not so important.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe you are looking for `MapThread`?

Comment: Ill take a look. Thanks for all the help.